# Type symbol not found in inner class

Tags: java, class, symbols, anonymous

**[EDIT: I've rewritten the code to further simplify it and focus on the issue at hand]**

I'm working on this particular piece of code:

```
    class SimpleFactory {
        public SimpleFactory build() {return null}
    }

    class SimpleFactoryBuilder {
        public Object build(final Class builderClazz) {
            return new SimpleFactory() {
                @Override
                public SimpleFactory build() {
                    return new builderClazz.newInstance();
                }
            };
        }
    }
```

However, the builder in the return statement triggers the error "Cannot find symbol newInstance". It's as if builderClazz wasn't recognized as a class object.

How can I make it work?

**EDIT: SOLUTION (thanks to dcharms!)**

The code above is a partial simplification of the code I was dealing with. The code below is still simplified but includes all the components involved and includes the solution provided by dcharms.

```
package com.example.tests;

interface IProduct {};
interface ISimpleFactory {
    public IProduct makeProduct();
}

class ProductImpl implements IProduct {

}

class SimpleFactoryBuilder {
    public ISimpleFactory buildFactory(final Class productMakerClazz) {
        return new ISimpleFactory() {
            @Override
            public IProduct makeProduct() {
                try {
                    // the following line works: thanks dcharms!
                    return (IProduct) productMakerClazz.getConstructors()[0].newInstance();
                    // the following line -does not- work.
                    // return new productMakerClazz.newInstance(); 
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    // simplified error handling: getConstructors() and newInstance() can throw 5 types of exceptions!
                    return null;
                }

            }
        };
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SimpleFactoryBuilder sfb = new SimpleFactoryBuilder();
        ISimpleFactory sf = sfb.buildFactory(ProductImpl.class);
        IProduct product = sf.makeProduct();
    }
}
```

Comment: Where did you define the `builder` method? Do you need to import it?

Comment: You mean, where did you define the `builder` class..

Comment: Yes @PaulHicks, my mistake. Thanks for catching it.

Comment: "builder" is a class passed as a parameter, therefore, in the context of this snippet of code is not defined yet. Let me see if I can further simplify the example. I suspect the generics are just making things unnecessarily cluttered for the resolution of the actual problem.

Comment: Is the `Class` type of that parameter definitely `java.lang.Class` and not a class of the same name in a different package?

Comment: Thanks Ian. Just checked. It is java.lang.Class indeed. Good thinking though. One never knows.

Comment: Just simplified the code removing generics as they were distracting and inconsequential for the problem at hand.

Comment: You still are using `new`. Please re-read my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot instantiate a new object this way. `builder` is a `Class` object. Try instead the following:

```
return builder.getConstructors()[0].newInstance(anInput);
```

Note: this assumes you are using the first constructor. You may be able to use `getConstructor()` but I'm not sure how it would behave with the generic type.

Comment: Thank you @dcharms for your answer. Unfortunately the "Cannot resolve symbol" message just shifted from "builder" to "getConstructors". =(

Comment: @manu3d it should be `getConstructors()` (it's a method, not a field, on `java.lang.Class`)

Comment: Thanks Ian. Just tried but getConstructors is still flagged as a "Cannot resolve symbol" error.

Comment: dcharms, as Ian mentioned getConstructors is a method. If you add the () parenthesis to your answer it will become correct and I'll accept it.

Comment: Thanks didn't notice the typo. Sorry about that.